# Select first value when filtering select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the script below, in a way that if "product color" is changed (selected) more than once, the first preselected / filtered item in fruit dropdown is actually the last one from previous array list and it should be the first one on that list.

- So if I chose Green it will filter to: "All", "Fruit 1", "Fruit 3",
  "Fruit 5"
- But when I switch to Yellow, preselected value in Fruit dropdown will be the last one from previous list, so “Fruit 5”

**How can I force it to be always first value?**

Example is below:

```js
$(function() {
  var $product = $('[name="filter-product"]');
  var $fruits = $('[name="filter-fruits"]');

  var $fruitsList = $fruits.find('option').clone();

  var fruit = {
    "Green": ["All", "Fruit 1", "Fruit 3", "Fruit 5"],
    "Yellow": ["All", "Fruit 1", "Fruit 3", "Fruit 4", "Fruit 5"]
  }

  $product.change(function() {
    var $selectedProduct = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $fruits.html($fruitsList.filter(function() {
      return $.inArray($(this).text(), fruit[$selectedProduct]) >= 0;
    }));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Color</h4>
<select name="filter-product">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
<h4>Fruit</h4>
<select name="filter-fruits">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="fruit1">Fruit 1</option>
  <option value="fruit2">Fruit 2</option>
  <option value="fruit3">Fruit 3</option>
  <option value="fruit4">Fruit 4</option>
  <option value="fruit5">Fruit 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var $product = $('[name="filter-product"]');
  var $fruits = $('[name="filter-fruits"]');

  var $fruitsList = $fruits.find('option').clone();

  var fruit = {
    "Green": ["All", "Fruit 1", "Fruit 3", "Fruit 5"],
    "Yellow": ["All", "Fruit 1", "Fruit 3", "Fruit 4", "Fruit 5"]
  }

  $product.change(function() {
    var $selectedProduct = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $fruits.html($fruitsList.filter(function() {
      return $.inArray($(this).text(), fruit[$selectedProduct]) >= 0;
    }));
    $fruits[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Color</h4>
<select name="filter-product">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
<h4>Fruit</h4>
<select name="filter-fruits">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="fruit1">Fruit 1</option>
  <option value="fruit2">Fruit 2</option>
  <option value="fruit3">Fruit 3</option>
  <option value="fruit4">Fruit 4</option>
  <option value="fruit5">Fruit 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this you can manually set the `selectedIndex` of the select back to `0` after updating the `option` elements, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $product = $('[name="filter-product"]');
  var $fruits = $('[name="filter-fruits"]');

  var $fruitsList = $fruits.find('option').clone();

  var fruit = {
    "Green": ["All", "Fruit 1", "Fruit 3", "Fruit 5"],
    "Yellow": ["All", "Fruit 1", "Fruit 3", "Fruit 4", "Fruit 5"]
  }

  $product.change(function() {
    var $selectedProduct = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $fruits.html($fruitsList.filter(function() {
      return $.inArray($(this).text(), fruit[$selectedProduct]) >= 0;
    }));
    $fruits[0].selectedIndex = 0; // select the first option
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Color</h4>
<select name="filter-product">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
<h4>Fruit</h4>
<select name="filter-fruits">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="fruit1">Fruit 1</option>
  <option value="fruit2">Fruit 2</option>
  <option value="fruit3">Fruit 3</option>
  <option value="fruit4">Fruit 4</option>
  <option value="fruit5">Fruit 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var $product = $('[name="filter-product"]');
  var $fruits = $('[name="filter-fruits"]');

  

  var fruit = {
    "Green": ["All", "Fruit 1", "Fruit 3", "Fruit 5"],
    "Yellow": ["All", "Fruit 1", "Fruit 3", "Fruit 4", "Fruit 5"]
  }

  $product.change(function() {
//moving this clone function inside onclick can help;
  var $fruitsList = $fruits.find('option').clone();
    var $selectedProduct = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $fruits.html($fruitsList.filter(function() {
      return $.inArray($(this).text(), fruit[$selectedProduct]) >= 0;
    }));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Color</h4>
<select name="filter-product">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
<h4>Fruit</h4>
<select name="filter-fruits">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="fruit1">Fruit 1</option>
  <option value="fruit2">Fruit 2</option>
  <option value="fruit3">Fruit 3</option>
  <option value="fruit4">Fruit 4</option>
  <option value="fruit5">Fruit 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: moving clone() function inside change event can help it to reset every time.